# Stack trace prints everything on one line in log file (Java)

Tags: java, logging, stack, trace, slf4j

I have a program that creates a log file, and outputs the stack trace of an exception thrown. However, the stack trace is only printed on a single line. Any ideas on how to break it up, without manually catching the exception and breaking it up line for line? or is this just how slf4j logs to a text file?

Log file

```
07-25-2013 11:11:27 [loggerError] - ERROR - [EXCEPTION] java.sql.SQLException, 
[STACK TRACE] [com.***.********.******.************.<init>(************.java:195), ***.***.*******.****.***********.main(***********.java:210)]
```

Code for logging

```
 loggerError.error("[EXCEPTION] {}, \n[STACK TRACE] {}", e, e.getStackTrace());
```

using myEclipse, logging with slf4j
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can add an exception directly in the .error() function and it will print all for you, why do you do that by hand?

Comment: @fge where's the fun in using round wheels? I have heard that for some road surfaces square wheels are better...

Comment: How are you viewing the log?  If you're on Windows but the log was created on Linux and your viewer doesn't cope with `\n` (instead of `\r\n`) you might see this.

Comment: I am viewing the log as a txt file that I had it write to on my C://

Comment: Only using windows, so no problem there. Don't want to use the exception directly in the .error() because this is for the big picture. Not logging for just one class, using a method I made (LoggerFunction) that had logging code and then import/calling it when I need it in another project.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Java's Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

With Logger, this should do the trick:

```
Logger = logger = Logger.getLogger(<YourClass>);
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, <your message>, e);
```

If you want to do it *the hard way* you should keep in mind that [getStackTrace() returns an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29), so you'll have to process it.

Comment: I would rather stick to slf4j rather than Java's logger. Thank you for your feedback about the getStackTrace though.

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this:

```
 loggerError.error("[EXCEPTION]", e);
```